# SQL "For each row" not working as intended/not using correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

EDIT: IT WORKS FINE I'M JUST DUMB

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reject_proposed_or_requested_courses
  after UPDATE
  ON public."Student_registers"
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (((new.register_status = 'approved'::register_status) AND 
  ((old.register_status = 'proposed'::register_status) OR (old.register_status 
   = 'requested'::register_status))))
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.reject_proposed_requested_courses();
```

on the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Student_registers"
(
  lab_grade real,
  exam_grade integer,
  register_status register_status NOT NULL,
  amka integer NOT NULL,
  serial_number integer NOT NULL,
  final_grade real,
  CONSTRAINT "Student_registers_amka_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (amka)
      REFERENCES public."Student" (amka) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "Student_registers_serial_number_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (serial_number)
      REFERENCES public."CourseRun" (serial_number) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

my key is (amka,serial_number) and the only thing that changes during the update for the trigger is the register_status.(however it is not yet declared as primary key for test issues).

also register_status type is here:

```
CREATE TYPE public.register_status AS ENUM
   ('proposed',
    'requested',
    'approved',
    'rejected',
    'pass',
    'fail');
ALTER TYPE public.register_status
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

basically when someone changes an apply to 'approved' i need to check if the apply is ok to be approved...otherwise it gets rejected by the trigger.
So, i made the following trigger-function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reject_proposed_requested_courses()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
if(((select count(*) from "Student_registers" sr2 where amka=new.amka and
 sr2.register_status='approved')<=10)and  --less than 10
   [...] (more checks that work just fine after many tests)

   )then return new;
 else update "Student_registers" sr1 set register_status='rejected' 
      where (old.amka=sr1.amka and old.serial_number=sr1.serial_number);
   return new;
 end if;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

my problem is with the condition "less than 10" ...each student can have 10 max applies 'approved', so each time i need to check if there are 10 applies approved under his amka...this works as intended if i try to do individually changes, but if i massively change all applies(more than 10) to approved the trigger just 'reject' all of them. My main concern is that the "for each row" does not really do the job i expect it to do. If there are 15 changes at the same time, i want to accept the first 10 'approve' and 'reject' the next 5 of them. What should i do to accomplish that?

thanks

Comment: `'approved'::register_status` looks wrong. What data type is the column `register_status`? Using a `before` trigger will be more efficient though as you don't need the `update` statement in the trigger

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done, added `create table` and explanation on `register_status` type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i get the `tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command` error when trying the trigger using `before`

Comment: Your "more checks that work just fine" appear to be the problem; with only the `count(*)` condition, I get the expected result. See here: http://rextester.com/NYXG55833

Comment: By the way, this won't work if two users run updates concurrently. You'll need either explicit locks or `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation.

Comment: @NickBarnes i apologise deeply for not testing it on its own...the "more checks" were working just fine on their own and when i added this extra "10 applies max" piece of code it started bugging so i just assumed it was the "10 applies max" fault without testing it on its own...sorry for wasting your time. the rest of the code includes 5 more tables so i   dont want to bug you with more of this, i messed up enough so far... i will also look into the second issue you suggested, thanks!

Comment: @LaprimoSiesta: No need to apologise, happy to help :)